# How to use $variables from theme setting in main menu

Tags: 8, theming

I make some field in theme setting and can use them normali in block, page, but when I want to use them in main menu its dont work.

```
function saka_theme_preprocess_menu__main (&$variables, $hook) {

    $variables['social_url_fb'] = theme_get_setting('social_url_fb','saka_theme');

}
```

and in menu--main.html.twig I write this..

```
{% for item in items %}
                <li {{ item.attributes }} >
                    <a  href="{{ item.url }}"  {{ item.attributes }} > {{ item.title }}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ social_url_fb }}" class="btn-social-menu"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use name suggestions with double underscore in preprocess function names.

You have to replace this with an if statement in code:

```
function saka_theme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    $variables['social_url_fb'] = theme_get_setting('social_url_fb','saka_theme');
  }
}
```